# Acer Aspire 3 A315-31-C6D4 bios password

Tags: bios, passwords, acer-aspire

My laptop bios is locked with pass that i lost it...after I enter 3 different password, now is asking an unlock code or something, like in image:[Enter unlock password key 2042932810](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Fpt.jpg)

Someone please help me with the appropiate code/password????

Comment: I'm sure ACER can help you...

Comment: Maybe you can remove the internal battery to reset all BIOS configurations and passwords. Did you try that? For that you'll need to _hard open_ your device, sometimes to find the battery is a hard thing but not impossible.

Comment: @adamitj True, that usually works but I wouldn't advise users to do that without alerting to the fact that it might **void the warranty**. In cases like this ALWAYS contact the brand's tech support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this procedure :

- Enter three wrong passwords.
- You will get a "System Disabled" scare message, which is not a great deal
  since this condition is cleared up by a reboot.
- Note the number below the message

  [image]
- Go to the website [BIOS-PW.org](http://bios-pw.org/), type in that number
  and press the "Get password" button.
- It will give you back a set of passwords for different BIOS brands that match that checksum.
- Reboot and try the password that agrees with your computer.